Minimizing a Function with Nonlinear Constraints
I am trying to minimize the function  $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$  subject to the constraints:
$$
x^3 + \frac{x}{x + y} y^3 - c \leq 0,
$$
$$
x \geq 0,
$$
$$
y \geq 0.
$$
I have attempted to use the method of Lagrange multipliers but encountered difficulties due to the complexity of the constraints. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Defined the Lagrangian:
$$ \mathcal{L}(x, y, \lambda, \mu, \nu) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} - \lambda \left( x^3 + \frac{x}{x + y} y^3 - c \right) + \mu x + \nu y$$
Computed the partial derivatives and set them to zero:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \lambda \left( 3x^2 + \frac{y^4}{(x + y)^2} \right) + \mu = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{y^2} - \lambda \frac{xy^2}{(x+y)^2} \left( 3x + 2y \right) + \nu = 0$$
Complementary slackness conditions
$$\lambda( x^3 + \frac{x}{x + y} y^3 - c) = 0$$
$$\mu x = 0$$
$$\nu y = 0$$
And $$\lambda \ge 0, \mu \ge 0, \nu \ge 0$$
To find critical points ($x,y,\lambda, \mu,\nu$), first assume $\lambda = 0$.
But $\lambda = 0$ if and only if $x \to \infty$ and $y \to \infty$. However, this violates the condition
$$x^3 + \frac{x}{x + y} y^3 - c < 0.$$
Hence $\lambda \neq 0$.
I am unsure how to proceed from here. Could someone guide me on how to approach this problem, or suggest a numerical method that could help solve it?

